# Excel Run Length Encoding

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

If I have a column of data in Excel that looks like:

```
1
1
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
```

Is there an easy way to convert it into a run length list that looks like this instead:

```
3 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
```

(Three 1's, followed by one 0, followed by one 1, followed by two 0's, followed by two 1's)

I'd strongly prefer to stick with formulas of some sort because they're more transparent to some of the other people I'm working.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now.  You are trying to reduce the size of the list to only include the info about count and item... so that you still keep all of the info?  Can you edit your last row of out then to show `2   1` since it ends in ones.

Comment: @Byron exactly, and fixed.

Comment: you'd need look-ahead. are there any in-built excel look-ahead routines?

Comment: You could get the information using the Subtotal wizard with Count, although it won't be formatted as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am neither saying this is easy nor elegant, and imagine that someone can improve on it. I am indebted to Mike Girvin for the last two formulas.

Assuming that the original data is in Column A starting with A1:

- Populate B1 with 1 and B2 and down with the formula
  `=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)`
- Populate C1 and down with the formula `=IF(B2>B1,"",B1)`
- Populate D1 and down with the formula `=IF(C1="","",A1)`
- Populate E1 and down with the formula
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$1:$C$100)-ROW($C$1)+1)/($C$1:$C$100<>""),ROWS(E$1:E1))),"")`
- Populate F1 and down with the formula
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$1:$D$100)-ROW($D$1)+1)/($D$1:$D$100<>""),ROWS(F$1:F1))),"")`

Comment: I might be able to use a filter that excludes blank cells in place of the formula in the last two columns.  Depends on how nicely it plays with downstream logic in the sheet on Monday morning.

Comment: If it's not obvious to anyone else reading this answer; if you need more than 100 data points the column E/F formulas will need edited to take a larger input range.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Out of curiosity, did you use the filter for columns C and D or Mike's formulas for columns E and F?

Comment: I accepted this morning after confirming it worked on the production spreadsheet (needed to make sure it didn't need tweaking to play nice with everything else that one was doing.)  I had to use the formulas:  Filters don't update every time calls to random regenerated the bit sequence I was using as input and changed the rows that needed filtered as a result.